# Efficient way of creating numpy array of fixed size tuples from bytes

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to convert bytes to numpy array of fixed size tuples (2 or 3 doubles) and it must be 1d array.
What I managed to get is:
`values = np.fromstring(data, (np.double, (n,)))` - it gives me 2d array with shape (105107, 2)

```
array([[0.03171165, 0.03171165],
       [0.03171165, 0.03171165],
       [0.03020949, 0.03020949],
       ...,
       [0.05559354, 0.16173067],
       [0.12667986, 0.04522982],
       [0.14062567, 0.11422881]])
```

`values = np.fromstring(data, [('dt', np.double, (n,))])` - it gives me 1d array with shape (105107,), but array contains tuples containing array with two doubles

```
array([([0.03171165, 0.03171165],), ([0.03171165, 0.03171165],),
       ([0.03020949, 0.03020949],), ..., ([0.05559354, 0.16173067],),
       ([0.12667986, 0.04522982],), ([0.14062567, 0.11422881],)],
      dtype=[('dt', '<f8', (2,))])
```

is there any efficient way to achieve 1d array like this?:

```
array([(0.03171165, 0.03171165),
       (0.03171165, 0.03171165),
       (0.03020949, 0.03020949),
       ...,
       (0.05559354, 0.16173067),
       (0.12667986, 0.04522982),
       (0.14062567, 0.11422881)])
```

Comment: While the `dt` case uses `()` those aren't tuples.  That's a structured array.  Why do you need tuples?  What dtype should the array have?  Why?

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't know an **efficient** way, but as nobody has so far posted any answer at all, here is a way that at least gets you the desired output. However, efficient it is not.

```
values = np.fromstring(data, (np.double, (n,)))
x = np.empty(values.shape[0], dtype=np.object)
for i, a in enumerate(values):
    x[i] = tuple(a)
```

I would add that if you have an array of objects, it so much negates the benefits of using vectorisation in numpy, that you might as well just use a list instead:

```
values = np.fromstring(data, (np.double, (n,)))
x = [tuple(a) for a in values]
```

A possible alternative approach to generating the array of tuples -- not sure if it is any faster -- would be to go via such a list, and convert it back into an array in such a way as to deliberately break the conversion to a nice ordinary 2-d array that numpy would otherwise do:

```
values = np.fromstring(data, (np.double, (n,)))
x = [tuple(a) for a in values]
x.append(None)
y = np.array(x)[:-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

I already solved the problem using this code:

```
names = ['d{i}'.format(i=i) for i in range(n)]
value = np.fromstring(data, {
    'names': names,
    'formats': [np.double] * n
})
```

Comment: Again, that's not tuples.  It's a structured array, with `n` fields. That's a good result, but you should be using the correct terminology.